# Dynamic Fields in for Loop

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex, for, apex-variable

Is there a way to dynamically change the fields within a for loop?

As an example, if I have for loop:

```
for(Account a: myQueryResult){
        if(a.parentId = fieldVariable){
            Do something
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to declare "parentId" as a variable that could be changed? For instance if I wanted to check on the value of a different field on the account?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you just use `get` instead. You can cache a `String` or `SObjectField`.

```
SObjectField field = Account.ParentId;
for (Account record : [SELECT ParentId FROM Account LIMIT 10])
{
    Object value = record.get(field);
}
```

Note that it returns `Object`. If you want to return a concrete type, you'll have to cast.

```
Id value = (Id)record.get(field);
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Lets say I declared "field" as "AlternateName". Also, I would have to cast value as a string. Could I then do: if(value = fieldVariable){ And this would work} ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a component that is reusable on additional objects. So the problem is that I won't be able to define field so directly. I would have two strings passed to the controller: Account and ParentId. How could I define "field" using two strings?

Comment: You might want to look at the Selector library.